# how to solve this error on windows??? droidgap unrecognized

Tags: ant, cordova, droidgap

i download phonegap but it's bin folder just contain droidgap with unknown type.
when i use this command in command prompt with ruby droidgap wiz the result is :
 droidgap is not recognized :(
i also install ant and sdk manager. and add their path to system path.i decide to use eclipse to build my android app(i write my app with js,css, html5). but when i make my app with eclipse browse button does not work & when i build it with phonegap browse button work. if you know solution please suggest it.

thanks in advane

Comment: i am facing the same but in a slightly different way. Please see the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095878/droidgap-wiz-command-not-finding-android-installation-in-git-bash if you can solve the thing.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a ruby executable file. To run droidgap you must have ruby installed.

refer here for installation of ruby https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

and make sure that you set the path to ruby2.0.3/bin

here is the missing set up guide by phil http://dev.tonic1394.com/2010/06/phonegap-the-missing-androidwindows-setup-guide/